# Open Source Tool which Convert Source Code from one Language to other

Tags: open-source

Is there any tool which converts the source code in one language to other...

Comment: what a great subcontracter you are.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a bit more specific than that....

Comment: To be more specific. I am actually looking for converting a code return in Java to C#

Comment: You didn't understand the concept of different programming languages, did you? :-/

Comment: It's called a transcompiler in general. There are many available, you might want to check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [TXL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXL_(programming_language)), a [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) tool that has been used to implement language-to-language translators.

EDIT: (after OP clarified his question slightly in a comment)
You aren't very clear about the translations direction: Java-to-C# or C#-to-Java.
However, this SO thread seems to address both to some degree:
[Is there an effective tool to convert C# code to Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811/is-there-an-effective-tool-to-convert-c-to-java)
(the link is really to convert-c#-to-java; SO apparantly can't put a # in a link).

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I know of that has anything like this is [LLVM](http://llvm.org) which provides a C backend, i.e. it should be able generate C code from any language for which there is an LLVM front-end.

Comment: LLVM won't convert C# to Java or vice versa.