# Convert an c# Winforms Application to Java

Tags: java, c#, winforms

Hello I have a problem me and my friend are currently developing a tool for an game, and we originally wanted to support only Windows, however a version for Mac Linux etc was requested, and I wanted to convert it to Java.

Is there a way to do this without redoing the entire code in Java ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an effective tool to convert C# code to Java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811/is-there-an-effective-tool-to-convert-c-sharp-code-to-java-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tools for converting codes but they are only working correctly with little code blocks. An entire project requires a different complier, framework, libraries etc.. So yes, you must redo the entire code only with little convertings with that tools. But I don't recommend that. They may split apart your code integrity.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get away without porting to Java, but rather leveraging .Net Core (currently in Release Candidate/Preview) which supports all the major platforms.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows